# FSL (preprocessing BedPostX) Error: Error in logfile. What does this mean?

Tags: python, image-processing, syntax-error

When I do BedpostX FSL preprocessing I get this message:

```
----- Bedpostx Monitor -----
1 slices processed out of 62
2 slices processed out of 62
.
.
.
59 slices processed out of 62
60 slices processed out of 62
An error ocurred. Please check file /Users/...../bedpostx.bedpostX/logs/bpx_postproc.e68944
/Users/..../bedpostx.bedpostX/monitor: line 15: kill: (9187) - No such process
logout

[Process completed]
```

So I checked the log file:

```
Error in logfile:  *File "/Applications/FSL/bin/imglob", line 78
    print "Usage: $0 [-extension/extensions] <list of names>"

                     ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
  File "/Applications/FSL/bin/imglob", line 78
    print "Usage: $0 [-extension/extensions] <list of names>"

                                      ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
  File "/Applications/FSL/bin/imglob", line 78
    print "Usage: $0 [-extension/extensions] <list of names>"

                               ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
  File "/Applications/FSL/bin/imglob", line 78
    print "Usage: $0 [-extension/extensions] <list of names>"

                              ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'*
```

But I dont know really what it means. It is really strange cause the process was almost done (see above at 61 it stopped). I got almost every outputs. So my questions are:

1. What does the error mean?
2. Is the process still completed? (see above there it is said)
3. If not what can I do to fix the problem?

Here is another screenshot:

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

The bedpostx command is a shell script which uses sometimes Python environment itself. Due to the fact that on my system Python 3.5 was installed, the error occurs. So I just started the bedpostx command again but this time in a Python 2.7 environment terminal.